# Allow gridview columns to be resized by user

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I would like to allow the user to resize the columns in my datagridview just like in this gif. https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/columns/images/gridview-columns-rezise-columns001.gif

I tried to add AllowUserToResizeColumns="True" but for some reason it doesn't work for me here is my datagridview header code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="editingGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="false" DataKeyNames="compras_id"
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged" 
                 CellPadding="3" AllowUserToResizeColumns="True" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" onsorting="grdPurchases_Sorting"  GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
                <PagerSettings  Mode="Numeric" />
```

What can I do to get the columns to be resizable by the user. Thank you

Comment: `Resize column` on client side achieved by JS. HTML `table` (generated by `GridView`) doesn't support this feature by default.

Comment: Yes, I found exemples with javascript and html table but since I have a gridview I am not sure how to relate the two together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out that I needed to use javascript for it to work as Alex told me so here is my solution

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/colResizable-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         if ($.cookie('colWidth') != null) {
             var columns = $.cookie('colWidth').split(',');
             var i = 0;
             $('.mGrid th').each(function () {
                 $(this).width(columns[i++]);
             });
         }

         $(".mGrid").colResizable({
             liveDrag: true,
             gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip'></div>",
             draggingClass: "dragging",
             onResize: onSampleResized
         });

     });

     var onSampleResized = function (e) {
         var columns = $(e.currentTarget).find("th");
         var msg = "";
         columns.each(function () { msg += $(this).width() + ","; })
         $.cookie("colWidth", msg);
     }; 
</script>  

  <asp:GridView ID="editingGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="false" DataKeyNames="compras_id"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged" 
         CellPadding="3" AllowUserToResizeColumns="True" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" onsorting="grdPurchases_Sorting"  GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
        <PagerSettings  Mode="Numeric" />
```